# Make both Guild Command and Global Command work together Discord.js v13?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make slash command on my bot by following [Discordjs Guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#registering-slash-commands). According to this, there are guild command (only work on some servers) and global command (work on all servers have the bot).
But I just can make guild or global command work only, not both.

So is there anyway to make both of it work together?

For example: I have 2 slash command: cmd_1 and cmd_2,
i want to make cmd_1 globally and cmd_2 only for my server.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You can just deploy cmd_1 globally and cmd_2 to your desired server. Take a look [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#guild-commands) on how to add a command to a guild and [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#global-commands) to add a command globally. The only difference really is if you either use the `applicationGuildCommands` or the `applicationCommands` method. The former is the method to add commands to one guild only whilst the latter is used to push commands globally.